# How to order by fields in Django

Tags: django

For my case it will be very important to get the order right. I need to sort my MonthlySpending objects by its index. I have tried the dictsort from django template but does not work.

I have also included the ordering in my models, however, the ordering is not shown in the HTML but it does show in the admin.

Are there anyways i can sort my objects by its index?

**HTML**

```
{% for month in object.monthlyspending_set.all|dictsort:"index" %}
    <tr class="yeardata ">
        <td>{{ month.name }}</td>
        <td>$ {{ month.monthly_income }}</td>
        <td>$ <a href="{% url 'finances:detail' month.slug %}">{{ month.target_savings }}</a></td>
        <td>$ {{ month.actual_savings }}</td>
        <td>{{ month.percentage_met }} %</td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
```

**Models.py**

```
class MonthlySpending(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    annualspending = models.ForeignKey(AnnualSpending, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    index = models.IntegerField()
    slug = models.SlugField()
    objects = models.Manager

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['index']
```

Comment: Remove the `dictsort` (and actually it is an anti-pattern to write queries in templates anyway).

Comment: have removed the dictsort as it didnt work but do you have a way to sort by field in the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using `order_by` on your queryset before passing it down. Documentation is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/). You can do something like `some_query_set.order_by("index")`in your views.

Comment: Cool, glad i could help.

Answer (score 3):

```
object.monthlyspending_set.all().order_by('index') -> ascending order

object.monthlyspending_set.all().order_by('-index') -> descending order
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#order-by